# do while (true) while sys.o.print("Hi"); while(false);

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I don't understand the flow of:

```
do 
while(true)
System.out.println("Hi");
while(false);
```

For me, it seems, "Hi" should be printed only once, whereas it gets into infinite loop.

Comment: Can you please post the code in proper format?

Comment: you really should clarify this with some braces. In the absence of braces, sys.o.print will bind to while(true) : hence the infinite loop. The do throws me a little - I am surprised you don't have syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

This will loop for as long as the condition is `true`, which is forever.

```
while(true) 
    System.out.println("Hi");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just paste them like that, you will see the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    do
        while (true)
            System.out.println("Hi");
    while (false);
}
```

The do-while structure is separated and the inner loop runs (forever). This is one reason why it is always a good idea to put `{` and `}` for there items

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop will be called once, but since it's an infinite loop, it will stay there forever.

Answer (score 0):

In a do-while loop, the "while" condition is checked after the first execution of loop. In your case:

```
do{
  your code;
}while(false);
```

Now as your code is:

```
while(true)
  System.out.println("Hi");
```

which is an infinite loop, the condition of do-while loop will never be checked.